# How do I check if a room is active/exists in Jitsi Meet Android SDK?

Tags: android, jitsi

I'm building a chat app, using Jitsi Meet Android SDK for the calling feature. I want to display a banner at the top of the chat room if there is an active call (conference). How do I check if a conference room exists/active without joining? The user that performs the check already know the conference room ID/name and have permission to join the room.

I have already read the [documentation](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk), but it doesn't have any information on this.